# Physical and dynamical components the four potential

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, gauge-symmetry

I have a question regarding the four-potential and its gauge symmetry.

We have a gauge freedom:
 $A_{\mu} \rightarrow A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}\chi$ 
Such a transformation does not alter the EM field.

Now my questions are:

How do I find the gauge invariant components of $A_{\mu}$? I guess it is everything which cannot be written as a total derivative, but how do I make this explicit? Also which components are dynamical and which non-dynamical?

What is the physical part of $A_{\mu}$? None of the components individually I guess, these can be altered by the gauge. But what part is physical?

I realize the answers to these questions probably overlap to some degree but I am clueless how to go about finding the answers and interpreting them.

Thank you!

Comment: To what extent are you familiar with the process of "choosing a gauge" like the Coulomb gauge?

Comment: This is ultimately a very subtle issue, e.g., see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect . No individual component of $A$ at a given point is in any way physically meaningful all by itself. There are a couple of invariants that are clearly physically meaningful, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_electromagnetic_fields#Invariants , but they don't constitute all the physics.

Comment: I think I am familiar with choosing a gauge. If we were to use the Coulomb gauge we would choose A in such a way that div(A)=0 and the electric potential also to be 0. If we choose the Coulomb gauge, can we then make gauge invariant and dynamical components more explicit?